# Java set value of array in position

Tags: java, arrays, string, element

I am trying to set value of an array element in a certain position instead of null. But its not working properly and not being set accordingly. Below is my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    if(footballResults[i] == null)
    {
       footballResults[i] = "Game Not Started";
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("Game "+num+". "+footballResults[i]);
    }
    num++;
}
```

Comment: "its not working properly" doesn't tell us anything about what you expected vs what actually happened. It would also help if you'd indent your code more readably.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list for ideas about what I think makes a good question.

Comment: do you have any output? is `footballResults` a `string[]`? where do you define it?

Comment: Did you put `String[] footballResults = new String[5];` somewhere?

Comment: @KurtCamilleri: just say what "it's not working properly" actually means.

Comment: If the array has not already been defined as being of length 5, you can't just go and shove things into it. But the code you posted will work OK if the array is correctly defined. Show us how you defined your array.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to print array in set position in sorted order then first sorted your array and then print your elements:-

```
   Arrays.sort(footballResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

You provided few information, but i guess you may actually want to print the assigned value, so you need to print it outside the else statement. Hope this helps in any way.

```
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            if(footballResults[i] == null)
            {
               footballResults[i] = "Game Not Started";
            }

            System.out.println("Game "+num+". "+footballResults[i]);

            num++;
        }
```